# Alias Signature Updating via Email Settings API

Tags: java, email, alias, digital-signature, google-admin-sdk

1. Google Apps Email Settings API allows you to create new aliases (Send mail as) but I can't find a way to update the signature for the alias accounts only the signature for the account it self.

   On the Gmail Settings >> General Tab : Signatures , you can define the signature for each alias ... I need to update all that signatures. Is there a way to retrieve and update ALIAS signatures via Email Settings API ?
2. What is the corresponding API for Email Settings in the new Google APIs Client Library for Java or is it wrong to say it is new and it is replacing gdata-java-client API

Note: Yes, I'm talking about Google Apps domain users

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no way (to my knowledge) to update the signature of aliases programmatically because there is no exposed API. You can only do it through the UI.
2. The Email Settings API is still based on the old Gdata Atom based API infrastructure. Google are pretty good with their communications about this and would update the [Email Setting API main page](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/).

Answer (score 0):

> Aliases are also used to manage signatures for an account.

Sounds like Account == Alias for signatures?

> You may also configure email signatures for each alias. For example, to set the signature for the user's primary address:

```
SendAs primaryAlias = null;
ListSendAsResponse aliases = gmailService.users().settings().sendAs().list("me").execute();
for (SendAs alias: aliases.getSendAs()) {
    if (alias.getIsPrimary()) {
        primaryAlias = alias;
        break;
    }
}
SendAs aliasSettings = new SendAs().setSignature("I heart cats.");
SendAs result = gmailService.users().settings().sendAs().patch(
        "me",
        primaryAlias.getSendAsEmail(),
        aliasSettings)
        .execute();
System.out.println("Updated signature for " + result.getDisplayName());
```

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/alias_and_signature_settings#managing_signatures